# how to enable publish option at page level in sharepoint 2010 for team site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a team site with publishing enabled.i want to enable publish option for home page of site, so that i can apply page layout for home page.publish option for home page is currently disabled in ribbon.

Comment: I assume you created page as simple web part page (you had done this before enabled publishing)?

Comment: it was the default home page of sharepoint server team site.